# Can not play audio data from Google TTS api for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I am using google tts api for text to speech. I can get data, But don't play in AVAudioPlayer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
dataOutput = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
tts = [[GoogleTTS alloc] init];
//NSLog(@"Here");
[tts convertTextToSpeech:@"test 1 2 3" withCompletion:^(NSMutableData *data) {
    dataOutput= data;
    NSLog(@"data1 = %@",data);
    [player setDelegate:self];
}];

[self performSelector:@selector(loadUrl) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)loadUrl{
NSLog(@"data2 = %@",dataOutput);
NSURL *audioFileURL = [self fileURLWithFileName:@"converted.mp3"];

[dataOutput writeToURL:audioFileURL atomically:NO];
[self playAudioFromURL:audioFileURL];
}

- (void) playAudioFromURL: (NSURL*) url {
NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
}

- (NSURL*) fileURLWithFileName: (NSString*) fileName {
NSURL *documentDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
return [documentDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}
```

Comment: Is `dataOutput` nil? Is `converTextToSpeech:withCompletion:` async? Why don''t you check the `error` parameter of `initWithContentOfURL:error:`?

Comment: dataOutput not nil.

Comment: And what about the error parameter? Also, call `loadUrl` in the completionBlock, not with a performSelector with delay.